# function making

Tags: python, functional-programming

Hi I am new to functional programming. What i did is

```
>>> g=lambda x:x*2
>>> f=g
>>> g=lambda x:f(f(x))
>>> g(9)
36
```

Now, it is not creating `g` as a nonterminating recursive function - `g(x)` is transformed to a new function which gives the result `g(g(x))`.

```
>>> f=g
>>> g=lambda x:f(f(x))
>>> f(8)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I expected `g` to be transformed into a function which gives the result `g(g(g(x)))`, according to the first definition of g(x). Why does it not? Is it possible to make a new function which results in `g(g(g(...(g(x))....)))` for a certain number of iterations in this way?

Comment: @eric, i am posting that edits as another doubt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `f = g` for the second time, f becomes `lambda x: f(x)`. Closures are created by name, not by value.

---

This becomes easy with a helper function:

```
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

square = lambda x:x*2
g = square
for i in xrange(4):
    g = compose(g, square)
```

Comment: Saying closures go only by names is a bit misleading. If you have multiple variables with the same name, a closure will always refer to the one that was in scope when the closure was created, not just any variable with the same name. I suggest rephrasing this to something like "Closures close over variables, not values".

Comment: is there any way to perform g=lambda x:newcopy(f)(x) so that new re-assignments of f wont affect g??

Comment: compose is also available in the `functional` module (get from pypi).

Comment: @Marcin: Probably not worth getting a module for just two lines of code.

Comment: @Eric Unless he wants to do this in more than one project. Or if composition is not the only piece of functional programming that interests OP.

Answer (score 4):

In python, variables are names mapped to values, not values themselves (everything is a reference).  Also, you can think of lambda as storing text that can be evaluated.  The following will illustrate

```
a = 2
f = lambda x: a*x
f(2) # This gives 4
a = 3
f(2) # This gives 6
```

This should clear up why you are getting infinite recursion.

In answer to your question about recursing, here is a little hack that might do

```
g = lambda x, n: n > 0 and g(x, n-1)**2 or x
```

Then `g(2,3)` would be `(((2)^2)^2)^2 = 256`.

Comment: No, pass-by-reference is a calling discipline for functions. That has nothing to do with assignment using the `=` operator. Incidentally, python uses call-by-value.

Comment: @Marcin yes. Sloppy terminology on my part. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
g=lambda x:x*2
f=g
g=lambda x:f(x)
```

is equivalent to:

```
f=lambda x:x*2
g=lambda x:f(x)
```

When you call `g`, you get whatever `f` happens to be defined in the global (or enclosing) scope.

what you're expecting is something like:

```
f=lambda x:x*2
g=lambda x, f=f:f(x)
```

That captures the value of f in the outer scope at the time the `lambda` *expression* is evaluated.