# function making

Tags: python, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function making](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428560/function-making)

```
>>> g=lambda x:x+1
>>> composition=lambda f,g:(lambda x:f(g(x)))
>>> f=g
>>> f=composition(f,g)
>>> f(9)
11
>>> f=composition(f,g)
>>> f=composition(f,g)
>>> f=composition(f,g)
>>> f(9)
14
```

Instead of using function composition(f,g) ,i did the following

```
>>> f=g
>>> f=lambda x:f(g(x))
>>> f(8)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I just aimed substituting function composition with corresponding lambda expression. I am confused about why  f=composition(f,g) is not producing recursion but f=lambda x:f(g(x)) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one:

When you call `composition(f, g)`, you are creating a closure around the contents of those variables.  The lambda being returned is looking for the variable names `f` and `g` in its local scope - they'll both be references to the `g` lambda created on the first line.

For the second one:

In the second one, when `f` is called, it looks for `f` in its "local" scope, which is actually the global scope - and finds *itself*, hence creating infinite recursion.

The key here is that the lookup of `f` happens at *execution*, not when the lambda is defined.

Answer (score 1):

When you write this:

```
f=lambda x:f(g(x))
```

The resulting lambda means "call whatever f is in scope on the result of calling whatever g is in scope on x".

When you write this:

```
f=composition(f, g)
```

The resulting function means "call whatever the first parameter to composition was on the result of calling whatever the second parameter to composition was on".

I'm not sure which part of the details you need to understand better to figure this out, but I'll take a guess. Argument passing in Python is always by reference, not by name. So, when you call composition(f, g) you're passing in the function object that f refers to, not the "variable" f. But when you define a lambda, that just happens in scope, so you're refering to f itself.

As a side note, this is part of the reason Guido doesn't like people using the lambda syntax. What's going on is a lot more obvious if you rewrite the code like this:

```
def g(x): return x+1
def composition(f,g):
  def composed(x): return f(g(x))
  return composed
f=g
f=composition(f,g)
```